# Wait for a coroutine to finish before moving on with the function C# Unity

Tags: c#, coroutine, unity-game-engine

I was working on making a unit move through a grid in Unity2d. I got the movement to work without problems.
I would want the function MovePlayer to wait until the coroutine is finished before moving on, so the program will wait until the player has finished the movement before issuing more orders.

Here is my code:
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Vector3 position;
private Vector3 targetPosition;

private float speed;

void Awake ()
{
    speed = 2.0f;
    position = gameObject.transform.position;
    targetPosition = position;
    GameManager.instance.AddPlayerToList(this);                     //Register this player with our instance of GameManager by adding it to a list of Player objects. 
}

//Function that moves the player, takes a list of nodes as path
public void MovePlayer(List<Node> path)
{
    StartCoroutine(SmoothMovement(path));
    //Next step should wait until SmoothMovement is finished
}

private IEnumerator SmoothMovement(List<Node> path)
{
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
    {
        targetPosition = new Vector3(path[i].coordinatesX, path[i].coordinatesY, 0f);

        float sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - targetPosition).sqrMagnitude;

        while (sqrRemainingDistance > float.Epsilon)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
            sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - targetPosition).sqrMagnitude;
            yield return null;
        }

        position = transform.position;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not wait for a coroutine in a function in the main thread, otherwise your game will freeze until your function ends.

Why don't you call your next step at the end of your coroutine?

```
private IEnumerator SmoothMovement(List<Node> path)
{
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
    {
        targetPosition = new Vector3(path[i].coordinatesX, path[i].coordinatesY, 0f);

        float sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - targetPosition).sqrMagnitude;

        while (sqrRemainingDistance > float.Epsilon)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
            sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - targetPosition).sqrMagnitude;
            yield return null;
        }

        position = transform.position;
    }
    //Next Step
}
```

Comment: thank you, what you said gave me an idea about how to dealing with my problem, thank you :)

Comment: Old post but I think its bad to write a function multiple times for a single coroutine.

Answer (score 3):

Also if this Question is answered, some people cannot use the solution from itectori, so here is my solution:

You could do

```
yield return StartCoroutine(yourCoroutine);
```

But in this case your function can not return void.