# How to wait Coroutine callback is executed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to wait StartCoroutine callback is executed.
Anyone knows how to do this?

```
public float getXXX() {
  var result;
  StartCoroutine(YYY((r) => result = r)); // how to wait this?
  return result;
}

private IEnumerator YYY(System.Action<float> callback) {
  LinkedList<float> list = new LinkedList<float>();
  while(timeleft > 0) {
    timeleft -= Time.deltaTime;
    list.add(transform.position.magnitude);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (WAITSPAN);
  }

  callback(list.max());
  yeild return true;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for a coroutine to finish before moving on with the function C# Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359236/wait-for-a-coroutine-to-finish-before-moving-on-with-the-function-c-sharp-unity)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate since it has a callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't try to wait or yield for a coroutine function to return from **non** coroutine function (`getXXX` function). It will block in that non coroutine function until this function returns preventing other Unity scripts to run.

To wait for a coroutine function(`YYY`) in the `getXXX` function, you must also  make the function you are making the call and waiting from in a coroutine function. In this case this is the`YYY` function, so that should be a corutine function too then you can `yield` it:

```
public IEnumerator getXXX()
{
    float result = 0f;
    yield return StartCoroutine(YYY((r) => result = r)); // how to wait this?

    //Use the result variable
    Debug.Log(result);
}
```

OR

If you don't want to make the `getXXX` function a a coroutine function then don't try to wait there. You can still use the result from the `YYY` coroutine function but don't try to return the result. Just use it to do whatever you want to do in that function:

```
public void doSomethingXXX()
{
    StartCoroutine(YYY((result) =>
    {
        //Do something with the result variable
        Debug.Log(result);

    }));
}
```

The idea of using coroutine is to be able to do something over multiple frames. The void function will just do that in one frame. You can't yield/wait in a `void` or non IEnumerator/coroutine functio.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to return some value on getXXX().And I have to use "yield return new WaitForSeconds()" in YYY. If I use this, caller method resume the proccess before entire YYY process finishied...Do you know how can I avoid this?

Comment: *"If I use this, caller method resume the proccess."* I don't understand. Could you be more specific?

Comment: In YYY, call WaitForSeconds at regular intervals.like .. while(time>0){ // some code   .. return (WaitForSeconds (1.0f)} When WaitForSeconds is called, processing of XXX will resume without waiting for completion of YYY processing.

Comment: Are you talking about the `public float getXXX()` function in your question?  Like I said in my answer you can't make it wait for a coroutine or wait with `WaitForSeconds` because `getXXX` **not** a coroutine function.

Answer (score 2):

You can only wait inside a coroutine. To do this, your getXXX() method should also be a coroutine. Something like this:

```
public float someOtherMethod()
{
    float result;
    StartCoroutine(getXXX(out result));
    return result;
}

IEnumerator getXXX(out float result)
{
    //more code here...
    yield return StartCoroutine(YYY((r) => result = r));
    //more code here...
}

IEnumerator YYY(System.Action<float> callback)
{
    //your logic here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something you may be able to call the class and use the methods inside this code and modify to use this is very similar to your code but less complex:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaitForSecondsExample : MonoBehaviour
{
   void Start()
   {
        StartCoroutine(Example());
   }

    IEnumerator Example()
    {
        print(Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        print(Time.time);
    }
 }
```

this code was taken from: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html
from there examples
The 5 is the amount of time it will wait unless you want to do this dynamically based upon something. Depends on what you want to do. However notice how they are calling the method Example() inside the StartCoroutine(Example()) and which will go to the IEnumerator Example() and within there you have WaitForSeconds(5); this will make the StartCoroutine wait for 5 seconds. This can be hardcoded or made to wait dynamically by calling another method within that class from within IEnumerator Example() this is just one of many ways you can attack this. Again depends on what you want to do. Actually, you might even be better off making this into a method that passes a value in to the method each time something like

```
    IEnumerator Example(float flSeconds)
    {
        print(Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flSeconds);
        print(Time.time);
    }
```

this way you can pass what is in your 
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
Every time

Comment: This does not answer the question. It shows how to wait for seconds only not how to wait for a coroutine function or a callback to return.