# Unity: make main thread wait until data loaded or time passed

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, hololens

I'm trying to get some Json data from a remote service by a URL. I know the WWW class can be used for this but I don't know if it is possible to wait for the response of this class before continuing the program. anyone who can help?

the coding example from the Unity docs https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html works async with the thread you activate it in. I tried waiting for the call to end but I keep bumping into the same problem.

It seems you can only wait for a async call with an async call. preferably I would like the call not to run async or to make my main thread wait until the call is completed.

I try to get my data in the following class:

```
    public String data { get; set; }
    public bool loaded { get; set; }


    public IEnumerator ReadData(String source) {
        using (WWW webClient = new WWW(source))
        {
            yield return webClient;
            data =  webClient.text;
            loaded = true;
        }
    }
```

I'm developing for a hololens as end device if that can help.

Comment: Maybe you can add some code examples to your question to show us what you have already tried, what was working and what was not?

Comment: I tried many "fixes" but non of them seem to work. The program doesn't wait and continues wit null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for a coroutine to finish before moving on with the function C# Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359236/wait-for-a-coroutine-to-finish-before-moving-on-with-the-function-c-sharp-unity)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean waiting for download to finish so you can work on the downloaded data:

```
private IEnumerator DownloadData()
{
    using (WWW www = new WWW(someURL))
    {
        yield return www; // Wait for download to finish

        // Once the code reaches here your download has finished.
        byte[] downloadedData = www.bytes;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
StartCoroutine(DownloadData());
```

Comment: yes that is what I want, but I would like to use the data in my main thread afterwards. I experienced the StartCoroutine to "start a new thread" or something similar in parallel with the main.

Comment: Unity is effectively single threaded and Coroutines are not threads, so you should be safe to use the downloaded data.

Comment: It still continues wit null. I'm certain my service returns data but I need to wait until I get it before continuing.

Comment: I'm trying to do it this way since I need the data outside of this class. 
        public String data { get; set; }
        public bool loaded { get; set; }


        public IEnumerator ReadData(String source) {
            using (WWW webClient = new WWW(source))
            {
                yield return webClient;
                data =  webClient.text;
                loaded = true;
            }
        }

I'll post it in the question above as well

Comment: 1. Are you getting null reference on `data = webClient.text`? 2. Are you certain your json link works? Try typing it into your browser and see if you get a json return.

Comment: 1. I don't know but when I try to access the data from the class it is always null. I would like to wait until the call returns it's data
2.Yes I'm sure it works (just tried is as well)

Comment: 1. Breakpoint on `data = webClient.text` and make sure webClient.text contains data. If it doesn't, check the object itself and look at webClient.bytes and see if it does. 2. Make sure to check `loaded == true` before accessing the data.

Comment: And how can I make my main thread wait until loaded becomes true but also give up its processor time. Is there some kind of Thread.Sleep method I'm missing?

Comment: I'm just looking for a Thread.Sleep like method in Unity for a coroutine. I want to wait unil the method inside is completely finished before continuing with the code.

Comment: If that's the case the equivalent is `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1)`

Comment: that seems to have done it. Thank you for your help and patience.