# Unity is trigger and projectiles deleting game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity3D game, I am trying to create a rocket that will explode when its trigger collider hits the map or a player, destroying the projectile and instantiating in my explosion prefab. But with this piece of code, my ground keeps disappearing when I playtest the game. There is nothing touching the plane. Here is my code.

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider c) 
{
    GameObject explosion = Instantiate (Explosion, c.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    if (c.CompareTag("Projectile"))
    {
        Destroy (c.gameObject);
    }
    StartCoroutine(Coroutine());
    Destroy (explosion);
}
```

Comment: What is `Coroutine()`? Also, you instantiate the explosion and then destroy it in the same frame. That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Explosion is removed immediately after the launch of the Coroutine, it does not wait until the Coroutinefinishes the work, so the removal must be moved to the end of the Coroutine.

Comment: See also: [Waiting for coroutine to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44359236/1663383)