# return only after StartCoroutine finished unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have some code that requests some data from a webserver. I do this in a function that takes some parameters and should return the returned data. See below for the code:

```
public string[] GetDBValues(int type, string[] data){
    string base_url = "http://localhost/artez/onderzoeks_opdracht/interface_test/get_elements.php";
    string typePrefix = "?type=";
    string dataPrefix = "data[]=";
    string uriString = base_url + typePrefix + type;
    foreach (string dataElement in data){
        uriString += "&" + dataPrefix + dataElement;
    }
    string[] db_objects = null;
    StartCoroutine(UrlData(uriString, (result) =>{
        string clean_data = Regex.Replace(result, @"[""\[\]]", "");
        db_objects = clean_data.Split(',');

    }));
    return db_objects;
}
```

but when i run this code the returned data is empty because the data empty array is returned before it is filled with the data from the webserver. How do i make it so the data is only returned after the web-request has finished?

I tried setting the return in the `StartCoroutine` but then the function wont compile.

If anything is unclear let me know so i can clarify!

Comment: This is not how coroutines work. See [Wait for a coroutine to finish before moving on with the function C# Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359236/wait-for-a-coroutine-to-finish-before-moving-on-with-the-function-c-sharp-unity)

Comment: yeah i see how it works, but i need to return a value from the coroutine. How would i go about this? since i cant just put `return db_objects;` in the coroutine.

Comment: You cannot rely on a coroutine completing in any given second. You either need to wait for the coroutine (by making the call that contains it also a coroutine) or by having the coroutine pass the data off to a holder object that both caller and coroutine can access (and then do null checks).

Comment: so if i wrap the main call to this function in a coroutine it works? But then i still have the same problem in the main coroutine?

Comment: *`or by having the coroutine pass the data off to a holder object that both caller and coroutine can access (and then do null checks).`*

Comment: i prefer not to do null checks all the time, since it is a one time event. It happens only once after an event is triggered.

Comment: You must, in some manner, wait for the coroutine to complete. In order to do this outside of a coroutine, you must store the data Somewhere Else and check to see if the data is there or not. You cannot get around this.

Comment: You can't do this unless you make `GetDBValues` to be a coroutine function too and and return `IEnumerator`. After this, you can use `Action` to return the result like I id in the `UrlData` question.