# unity c# using delegate chain with time delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback, delegates

I tried to use delegate chain like below, trying to make animation in unity:

```
public class Class1
{
    class Dele {

        delegate void MyDelegate();
        private MyDelegate dele;

        private int count = 0;

        public void Animate() {
            dele = new MyDelegate(DoIe);
        }

        IEnumerator Ie() {
            Debug.Log(count);
            count += 1;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        }

        private void DoIe() {
            StartCouroutine(Ie());
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                dele += DoIe;
            }

            dele();
        }
    }

    //call new Dele().Animate() here
}
```

I thought the Log will go like
1
(5 secs)
2
(5 secs)
...
10

but instead,
1
2
..
10
was logged at the same time.

If I want to callback another Ie after 5 second,
what should I do??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for a coroutine to finish before moving on with the function C# Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359236/wait-for-a-coroutine-to-finish-before-moving-on-with-the-function-c-sharp-unity)

Answer (score 1):

With coroutines it's the code *inside* the routine (the `IEnumerator` method) that runs later. The code *after* `StartCoroutine()` in your void-returning method above will run [synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean) (straight away), like you saw.

You don't need a delegate here at all. All you need is this:

```
IEnumerator Ie() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        Debug.Log(count);
        count += 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    }
}

private void DoIe() {
    StartCoroutine(Ie());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your class needs to inherit from MonoBehavious for StartCoroutine to work.
  Then in regards of your question: you need to start the coroutine with a delay, just adding them to a multicast delegate is simply not doing what you think you are